# Highcharts Semi circle donut - doesn't show small item value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to integrate Highchart "Semi circle donut" with the official [reference](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-semi-circle).

This chart doesn't behave well when the value for one parameter is quite high and for the other it is low. As seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ye9garLc/).

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>January<br>2022',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y: 60
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                distance: -50,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            center: ['50%', '75%'],
            size: '110%'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        innerSize: '50%',
        data: [
            ['Chrome', 100000],
            ['Edge', 11.97],
            ['Firefox', 5.52],
            ['Safari', 2.98],
            ['Internet Explorer', 1.90],
            {
                name: 'Other',
                y: 3.77,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
});
```

I have given a value of 100000 to chrome and for the rest, it is less than 20. In this case, chrome occupies almost all the space. The rest of the items are not visible much.

I need help if we can set the min-width to the rest of the items to at least show them to the user. In my case, I am not expecting more than 5 items in the chart.

I already tried "minpointlength" which didn't help.

Comment: You can normalize the values before inserting them into the chart

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess your data to reduce differences between values, store original values in a custom property and show it in a tooltip or data labels. For example:

```
const data = [
  ['Chrome', 100000],
  ['Edge', 11.97],
  ['Firefox', 5.52],
  ['Safari', 2.98],
  ['Internet Explorer', 1.90],
  ['Other', 3.77]
];

const processedData = data.map(dataEl => ({
  name: dataEl[0],
  y: dataEl[1] > 100 ? 100 : dataEl[1],
  custom: {
    realVal: dataEl[1]
  }
}));

// Data retrieved from https://netmarketshare.com/
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
      const total = this.series.points.reduce(
        (prev, curr) => prev + curr.custom.realVal,
        0
      );
      const percentage = this.custom.realVal * 100 / total;

      return `${this.series.name}: <b>${percentage}%</b>`
    }
  },
  ...,
  series: [{
    ...
    data: processedData
  }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v7bcjymw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data.custom